# How can I make led light strips effect, in EEVEE or even in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, shaders, lighting

I have tried a lot to make such a realistic led light effect, but couldn't do so. Tried making plastic material and placing point lights in it, but that didn't help. Even tried using emission, but that also turned into a failure. What shader nodes to use to create such an effect? If anyone could help me with this, that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try a *Translucent* node, mixed with a bit of *Emission*, and for the lights create some *Area* lights:

[image]

For more realism you could mix with a *Diffuse*, with a *Noise Texture* as factor:

[image]

Comment: You nailed the "led look" IMO, didn't knew about the translucent shader. Very cool !

Comment: @holybobine thanks  ;)